# List Intersect and Concat

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I wrote some expression to Intersect and Concat two lists TestListA & TestListB as below:

```
var c= TestListA.Intersect(TestListB)
                .Concat(ListA.Where(a => 
                    ListB.Any(b => b.EndsWith("999") 
                                && b.StartsWith(a.Substring(0, a.Length - 3)))));
```

I want to know how loop and other conditions looks like behind the scene and if I will write all this with the help of foreach then performance will degrade?

Comment: Are you sure there is a `foreach` behind the curtains? This only produces an `IEnumerable<>`, nothing is iterated yet.

Comment: i am not saying for each i am saying how this works and if i will write this into foreach then what will...

Answer (score 2):

You can get access to most of .net framework sources.

The methods you use here are listed below:

```
static IEnumerable<TSource> IntersectIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer) 
{ 
    Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);
    foreach (TSource element in second) set.Add(element); 
    foreach (TSource element in first)
        if (set.Remove(element)) yield return element;
}

static IEnumerable<TSource> ConcatIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second) { 
    foreach (TSource element in first) yield return element;
    foreach (TSource element in second) yield return element; 
}

public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate"); 
    foreach (TSource element in source) {
        if (predicate(element)) return true; 
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Where `Set` is an internal class which behaves like some kind of `HashSet`

`Intersect` and `Concat` methods itself just makes some verification of input parameters and then calls `IntersectIterator` and `ConcatIterator` respectively.

`Where` method also makes verification and then constructs an instance of `WhereEnumerableIterator<T>` class. This class when you iterate it behaves like the following code:

```
public IEnumerable<T> IterateWhere(IEnumerable<T> source, Funct<T,bool> predicate)
{
    foreach (var element in source)
    {
        if (predicate(element))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```